# Copy data between specific <td> tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, copy

I've a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td class="type">Order</td>
   <td class="orderid">1002</td>
   <td><button class="copy">Copy Row</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="type">Order</td>
   <td class="orderid">1004</td>
   <td><button class="copy">Copy Row</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="type">Refund</td>
   <td class="orderid">1004</td>
   <td><button class="copy">Copy Row</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've a script to copy data from a particular "#id" or ".class" element. What, I needed is to find a way to get the data of that particular row whenever, the Copy button is pressed. I want the columns 'orderid' and 'type' values of that particular row to be copied, but I'm not able to find a way to extract the data between the `<td>` tags with same class names.

Comment: Where do you want to copy the values of the row?

Comment: into the clipboard actually, but I already have the zeroClipboard plugin for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
      $('.copy').click(function(){
      var order_id =  $(this).parent().parent().find('.orderid').text();
      var type =  $(this).parent().parent().find('.type').text();
         alert(order_id);  ///this wil get you the value
      });
```

I made the result here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ahsVfB

check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <tr>
       <td class="type">Refund</td>
       <td class="orderid">1004</td>
       <button class="copy">Copy Row</td>
     </tr>


     $(".copy").click(
           function(event)
           {
             var copy=($(event.target).parent().find('.type'));
             var order=($(event.target).parent().find('.orderid'));
           }
         );
```

You must paste that copied date somewhere. Make this copy and order as global variables. When you click paste, use this variable's value

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please explain the '.targetCopy' and 'targetOrder' ? Are these class names ?

Comment: Yes Afzal,If its your target. Where do you want to paste. If you want to paste in another dom, use that id or class as `$('#id').text('copy')` similarly for order

Answer (score 0):

take a look on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3p29x2s9/11/

```
var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName("copy");
console.log(buttons);
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
buttons[i].onclick=function(){
    var columns = this.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var type= columns[0].innerText;
    var orderid=columns[1].innerText;
 alert(type + " "+orderid);   

}
}
```